# Ajax not working for dynamic key in data parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax function like this:

```
var vm=$.noConflict();
vm(document).ready(function(){
var loadMore=function(e)
            {
            var idd=vm(this).attr("id");
            alert(e.data.recordId);        //it return blog_comment_id if I provide static value to data key
            var aaa=e.data.recordId;
                vm.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"ajaxHTML.php",
                    data:({e.data.recordId: idd}),
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(res)
                            {
                            alert(res);
                                vm("#"+e.data.divId).html(res);
                            }
                    });
            }
```

and calling this ajax function like this, Actually I am trying to make it dynamic where I will provide div id and record id.

```
vm(function() { 
vm(".view_more").click({divId:"fgh",recordId:"blog_comment_id"},loadMore);
    });
```

it is not working If i provide data parameter like this:

```
data:({e.data.recordId: idd}),
```

working for

```
data:({blog_comment_id: idd}),
```

So how could I make it possible with dynamic key.

Help will be appreciate

Comment: have you tried array syntax instead of dot notation

Comment: yes, it works only if i use a non variable in data key...any idea???